# syntax error but no encoding declared (Django accessing DB table in postgresql

Tags: python, django, postgresql, python-2.7, powershell

I am just getting started with Django/Python/postgresql and have hit a problem. I have set up a project and within that project I have created an app called "daypass". I have created a models.py by using the following 
python manage.py inspectdb > models.py

that created my models file and I think I have tidied it up. This is what it looks like now:

```
class Facilities(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(db_column='Name', blank=True)  # Field name made     lowercase.
    address = models.TextField(db_column='Address', blank=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    city = models.TextField(db_column='City', blank=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    postcode = models.TextField(db_column='Postcode', blank=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    price = models.TextField(db_column='Price', blank=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    primary_key = "true"
class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'Facilities'


 class DjangoMigrations(models.Model):
 id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  # AutoField?
 app = models.CharField(max_length=255)
 name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
 applied = models.DateTimeField()

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'django_migrations'


class FacilitiesFacilities(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(db_column='Name')  # Field name made lowercase.
    address = models.TextField(db_column='Address')  # Field name made lowercase.
    city = models.TextField(db_column='City')  # Field name made lowercase.
    postcode = models.TextField(db_column='Postcode')  # Field name made lowercase.
    price = models.TextField(db_column='Price')  # Field name made lowercase.


class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'facilities_facilities'
```

although I am not sure what Facilitiesfacilities is - there is only one table, 'facilities' in the DB that I want to use.

I then did:
python manage.py validate
and got no errors
and then did
python manage.py syncdb
although nothing happened

So I then went into Python in my PowerShell (windows) and tried to do the following, from daypass.models import Facilities
where Facilities is the name of the table in the DB since I want to make sure I can access the record set that exists in the DB and I get this error,

PS C:\Users\nicka_000\documents\coding\websites_go_here\hideyhole> python
Python 2.7.9rc1 (default, Nov 26 2014, 09:19:41) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > from daypass.models import Facilities
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "daypass\models.py", line 1
> > >       SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xff' in file daypass\models.py on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://python
> > >       .org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details

Any ideas on what else I need to do?

NB when creating a new table and populating through Django API I had to put the name of the app in the settings file but I haven't done that for this legacy DB. If I put "daypass" into the settings.py I get an error that it doesn't exist (the daypass directory doesn't have a settings file in it i.e. it wasn't generated when I created the app. Do I need to copy in manually?

thanks for your help

Comment: Did you think to read the link that is helpfully provided in that error message, and do what it says?

Comment: yes but I don't understand what that means! I see all the words but I don't understand where to put the information - does it go into the settings file?

Comment: No, it goes into the file that is affected.

Comment: ok so in models.py... I also wasn't sure what my entry should say since I don't know what I am meant to be changing from/to

Comment: still doesn't work. I have put this at the top of the models.py file:c:/python27/python
-*- coding: latin-1 -*-

Comment: if you would be able to tell me what I need to cut/paste into my models.py file I would be very grateful

Comment: You could try to set your text editor up to produce utf8 encoding

Comment: thanks but that didn't work either :(